# How to program ethereum's infrastructure?

Tags: network

I would like to create an ethereum network with some changes in the infrastructure, for example - adding some encryption, change the proof of work function and more. 
Do you know some environments which enable to do such kinds of staff?

I know Microsoft's product called Azure, but pretty sure that it does noe enable the infrastructure programming.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is directly quite impossible.

But a fork of Etheruem called **Quorum** has done precisely what you mentioned by changing the proof of work as well as other changes.

The most interesting thing is probably that Quorum client keeps most of the components of the ethereum client but adds an other layer of prebuilt smart contracts that handle the encryption of transactions thus handeling the privacy issues that makes the original ethereum model less acceptable in the business world.

If the quorum team can do it, i think it is posible to add smart contract data encryption as well as any kind of modifications(dynamic / static) of the infrastructure if you can dig more into the ethereum sources.